# imagePickerController didFinishPickingImage not being called

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to save an image I take from a UIImagePickerController but I am not, well, being able to.

This is the code I am trying to use to save the image:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil); }
```

That function is simply not being called.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you assigned the `delegate` property of the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) instance ? It is needed if you want to be notified (thus, if you want your method to be called).

Comment: Actually that solved it. Had asked another friend that told me that too but forgot to close the question. Thanks anyway! :D